# Can you pass multiple paths to the Django runserver --pythonpath directive?

Tags: python, django

For each of my projects I create an apps directory that holds all the apps I need. Satchmo also has an apps directory. Can I do something like *python manage.py runserver --pythonpath=/path/to/my/apps /path/to/satchmo/apps*? Is there some separator that it can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `--pythonpath` option to runserver.  You either want to add it to your `.bashrc` file or in your `settings.py` file add something like the following at the top:

```
import os,sys
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT, 'to', 'my', 'apps')
sys.path.append(os.path.join('path', 'to', 'satchmo', 'apps'))
```